# $a^{-1}b \implies ba^{-1}$ for group $H$ with $a \sim b \impliedby ab^{-1} \in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

I have an issue with the following example proof, namely the part where $(ab^{-1})^{-1} = (b^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1}$. Why is that?

I would say $(ab^{-1})^{-1} = a^{-1}b$. Nowhere does it say that the operation of $G$ is commutative, so why then would it be allowed to reverse $a^{-1}b$ to $ba^{-1}$?

[image]

Note that this is the Example 2 mentioned above:

[image]

Example 3 would make sense to me, if the operation of $G$ is addition of integers, but it does not say so specifically, which makes me unsure if it is supposed to be interpreted this way or if I am missing something.

Comment: Try multiplying out your expressions.  In general $(ac)^{-1}=c^{-1}a^{-1}$.  indeed $c^{-1}a^{-1}ac=e=acc^{-1}a^{-1}$.  No commutativity is assumed.

Comment: Your title is impossible to understand, please modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mistaken about how inversion acts on products; in particular, for any group $G$ and any $a,b\in G$ we must have:
$$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}.$$
If you already know that inverses are unique, this is easy to verify; if you multiply it by $ab$ (on either side), you get the identity element $e$:
$$abb^{-1}a^{-1}=aea^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e$$
$$b^{-1}a^{-1}ab=beb^{-1}=bb^{-1}=e.$$
Basically, you need to reverse the order when taking an inverse in order to put the cancelling terms next to each other in the above product.

That is to say, order *does* matter, but inversion flips the order. The book's manipulation is therefore correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense now. This was not entirely obvious for readers of the book at the point in the book where this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

$(ab^{-1})(ba^{-1}) = a(b^{-1}b)a^{-1} = aa^{-1} = 1$.

This is what is true in general. For it to be the case that $(ab^{-1})^{-1} = a^{-1}b$, that's when you'd need things to commute.